# Conseguir numero fila sql

Tags: mysql, sql

LLevo un par de dias probando como conseguir el numero de fila de una consulta, y de hecho lo he conseguido pero al subir el código al servidor donde tengo alojada mi página me encuentro con un error de sintaxis. He revisado las versiones de mysql y en local tengo la version 8.0 mientras que en el servidor la 5.5

Necesito conseguir una consulta que me rescate las localidades mas visitadas del mundo limitando el numero de localidades por país y continente. El código que me funciona en local es el siguiente:

```
select * from
  (select * , row_number() over (partition by  id_continente order by visitas desc) y from
      (select *, row_number() over (partition by  id_pais order by visitas desc) x from lugar_localidades_top_site where id_site=:site and categoria >=:categoria and id_pais <> :pais_excluido) top
    where x <= :loc_por_pais) top_mundo
  where y <= :loc_por_continente
order by visitas desc
```

El error está en la función row_number() ya que mysql 5.5 no lo implementa. Alguna idea para solucionar el tema? (No puedo cambiar la versión del servidor)

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Siempre aclara en los tags que base de datos estas usando. Y porque necesitas el numero de fila? no alcanza con topear la cantidad de filas (no me acuerdo si era top en mysql o era otro)

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes la posibilidad de añadir una función, pon la que se detalla en [este](https://datamakessense.com/mysql-rownum-row-number-function/) post

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS rownum;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION rownum()
  RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
  set @prvrownum=if(@ranklastrun=CURTIME(6),@prvrownum+1,1);
  set @ranklastrun=CURTIME(6);
  RETURN @prvrownum;
END $$
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Para usarla:

```
select rownum() from table
```

Comment: No es posible, solo puedo hacerlo mediante una consulta